# Android - Google Maps integration empty grid

Tags: android, google-maps

I have tried to use Google Maps API in my app. I have made key fingerprint, inserted into app, I tried to see some map (doesn't matther what map is it now), but all I see is a empty grid. I have in manifest

> < uses-library
>   android:name="com.google.android.maps"
>   />

I have my build AVD targeted at Gogle Api's, and all I see is the empty grid. Do you know, what can be wrong? My next thought was about to use build maps and link to them from my current app, when I will additionally show my position. But is it possible?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.app.seven"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity android:name=".myAvis"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".menu"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">      
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".finActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">      
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".calendar"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">      
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".enquiry"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/enquiryTitle"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">      
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".update"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
              android:label="@string/updateString">     
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".photo"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".mapa"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />


</manifest>
```

Comment: I hope your internet connection is fine. Make sure you signed the app with the same cert used for map api key generation.

Comment: plz paste your manifest file completely.

Comment: currently I am signing app with default certificate given by the debug.keystore - should I make a new developer cert and sign it with it?

Comment: not sure what is happening. how you created API key?? is it like you created MD5 signature from keytool and entered that in Android Google Map API registration page? and then you got API key?

Comment: Problem is, that I don't have API key yet... when I use keytool, it will create my certificate, but, when I want his fingerprint pro Google Maps API certification, it gives me SHA1 fingerprint, even though I use -keyalg RSA when creating new key. Do you know whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is few steps that you can do to get MD5 key..

1. Use this command `keytool -list -keystore "..(navigate to).android\debug.keystore"`
2. It will ask you for password just press enter.
3. You will get some key paste that in http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html
4. Your API key will get generate in nice XML format.
5. Paste this key in you MapView and try again

Comment: THere is just one problem, even if I use RSA method when creating it, it will give me SHA1 not MD5 key and Google web does not accept SHA1...

Comment: I am using Windows 7 32 bit but i get MD5 key how come you are getting SHA1 key?

Comment: for windows c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin>keytool -list -keystore c:\.....debugk.keystore

Comment: @Waypoint>> You should write -v then, it says on the how-to site aswell though.

Answer (score 0):

The new (1.7) java generates SHA1 key as default. Add the -v option to the keytool parameter set, and you'll get an MD5 hash too.

Answer (score 0):

just put -v after the list like the write below these will give you the MD5 file

keytool -v -list -keystore "..(navigate to).android\debug.keystore"

Please +1 if this is usefull or you can check here

http://irahuldev.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-get-google-maps-api-key-for.html